# What is the 'alias' keyword in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Looks like it's not an alias.

`get-alias alias` error: This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'alias' does not exist.

and it's not a command

`get-command alias` error: The term 'alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Most probably `alias` is an alias to `get-alias` cmdlet, but where is it defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason, you can omit the `get-` from a `get-xxxx` cmdlet in PowerShell and it will add the `get-` for you.

For instance, you can type `hotfix` instead of `get-hotfix`

Comment: Or you can type `verb` for a list of verbs.

Comment: This is the answer. But I still see slightly different behavior for some, for example `process` vs `get-process` or `help` vs `get-help`

Comment: process is a reserved word, and help is a built-in function (which calls get-help).  This behavior (prepending get-) is kind of a last gasp by the engine to figure out what is going on. #Eris has some details from the trace-command cmdlet which gives some more details.

Answer (score 3):

`alias` is resolved as `Get-Alias`, and here's how I found out:

```
> Trace-Command -Expression { alias } -Name CommandDiscovery -PSHost
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Looking up command: alias

<A rather large number of lines deleted, showing exactly where it's looking>

DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Looking for alias in C:\bin\sysinternals
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : The command [alias] was not found, trying again with get- prepended
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Looking up command: get-alias
DEBUG: CommandDiscovery Information: 0 : Cmdlet found: Get-Alias  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAliasCommand

<actual output of get-alias>
```

Comment: Your rather large number of deleted lines slightly hides that has already looked and failed to find 16 variations of `alias` in each directory on `$env:PATH`, so while it saved 4 characters typing over `Get-Alias` it is risky to depend on this behaviour as you could easily get an errant file such as `alias.js` taking precedence.

Comment: That is true, I was focusing more on the `Trace-Command` invocation to let someone discover where the command was found, and in this case the fallback.

Comment: @Duncan `.js` isn't executable on Windows, so you wouldn't get that. And if they were executable, then your objection is "be careful asking PS to run a command by name because it might find a command by that name and run it"? In that case, be careful relying on `get-alias` to run the cmdlet because you might have an alias named `get-alias` that which does something else and is matched first. Better to always run `microsoft.powershell.utility\get-alias` to make sure you get the one you intend.

Answer (score 2):

It is a built-in provider: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847895.aspx

You can get the list of drives with `get-psdrive` and the list of providers with `get-psprovider`.

Comment: That's interesting. There remains something mysterious about `alias` though. You can do `dir alias:` or `dir env:`, but you can also do just plain `alias` whereas you can't do just plain `env`, so the keyword `alias` is special. But it is not itself an alias or a function, so what is it?

Comment: I think Mike Shepard has the correct answer. The fact that there is a provider which gives you a drive of the same name isn't related to the use of `alias` as short for `get-alias`.